# After inserting multiple rows in the temporary table, a new row will be inserted at the end of the temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone help me how to code this on SQL:
I have this temporary table:

**TableX:**

```
ID  Code1  Code2  Sold    Money1      Money2   ISCode
 1   GB     GB     10    100.000000              1
 1   2GB    2GB     5    150.000000              1
 1   AB     NULL    1    150.000000              0
 1   CB     BK      1    150.000000              0
 1   NULL   DE     NULL  150.000000              1
```

I need to compute each row for Money2 Column.  The logic is this:

1. check the rows ISCode= 1
2. compute the Money2 for each row by this formula: Money1/Sold

I then need to Insert this new row at the end of the row in the temporary table: TableX

```
    ID  Code1  Code2    Sold   Money1        Money2     ISCode
     1  total   total    15   400.000000    16.670000    1
```

The logic of

1. **Sold** for the new column is Add all the sold in the rows where ISCode = 1
2. **Money1** for the new column is Add all the money1 in the rows where ISCode = 1
3. **Money2** for the new column is Money1/sold. but there is a row that has null values in the sold column so it will be excluded in the computation of Money2.

   ```
      sold = 10 + 5 = 15
      money1 = 310.000000
      money2 = 400.00000/15   -- Row #3 will be excluded in the computation of money2

   ID  Code1  Code2    Sold    Money1      Money2     ISCode
     1   GB     GB     10    100.000000   10.000000    1
     1   2GB    2GB     5    150.000000   30.000000    1
     1   NULL   DE     NULL  150.000000    NULL        1

     1   total  total  15    400.000000   16.670000    1
   ```

Is this possible using temporary tables or it is much better to use Table value parameter table for this scenario above?

---

SAMPLE DML AND DDL

```
CREATE TABLE #tableX(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Code1] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [Code2] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [Sold]  [int] NULL,
    [Money1] [money] NULL,
    [Money2] [money] NULL 
 )
 
 INSERT INTO #tableX(
    [ID],
    [Code1],
    [Code2],
    [Sold],
    [Money1],
    [Money2]
 )VALUES(
   1,
   'GB',
   'GB',
   10,
   100.000000,
   NULL
 ),
 (
   1,
   '2GB',
   '2GB',
   5,
   150.000000,
   NULL
 ),
 (
   1,
   'AB',
   NULL,
   0
   150.000000,
   NULL
 ),
 (
   1,
   'CB',
   'BK',
   1
   150.000000,
   NULL
 ),
 (
   1,
   NULL,
   'DE',
   NULL
   150.000000,
   NULL
 )
```

Comment: You've removed the [[tag:sql-server]] tag here, so what RDBMS *are* you using?

Comment: There's no end of a table, because in SQL, tables are an *unordered* bag of rows. Creating and manipulating a temp table strongly suggests you're thinking about your problem *procedurally*, which isn't a good fit for SQL, which works best when you can compose as much as possible into a single query and let the *database engine* work out what the right order to perform tasks is. Within that query, you may be able to using `GROUP` and `ROLLUP` to produce a total row *in the result set*, but you shouldn't be storing such a row.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Does it mean I need to do all the computations in the query in one insert query?

Comment: @Larnu I am using mssql

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that preparing the result set in a temp table at all is the mistake. Get rid of the temp table. Get rid of the insert. Just write a `select` that tells the system *what you want the complete result to look like*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Let's say, we will use the ordinary table, the expected result is still the same. I need to add a new fix column that will compute Money2.

Comment: @moana27, Damien has a point here - "money2" doesn't need to be a column on the actual table, just run a `select id, code1, code2, sold, money1, (money1/sold) as money2` (the IsCode is not on your sample, so i don't know where it comes from) and if you add that column just place the division in a `case when Iscode = 1 then money2/sold ELSE NULL END` block

Comment: @SammuelMiranda may I ask how about the inserting of the new column? is it possible to insert it in the temp table assuming that there are already rows that are saved in the table?

Comment: surelly - if i understood you correctly - since you want to fill up a column that is null, and the data is already there, you would `UPDATE #tableX SET money2 = money1/sold WHERE iscode = 1` and there it is, after inserting all the columns just update the hole table, os at your insert calculate the money2 column in advance, using the `case` block - i'll make an answer of it to see if i can make a more comprehencive example, one minute

Answer (score 1):

Ok, following some comments before, check if this is what you meant.

You have this table (that is a temp table)

```
DECLARE @tableX AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Code1] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [Code2] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [Sold]  [int] NULL,
    [Money1] [money] NULL,
    [Money2] [money] NULL,
    [IsCode] [bit] NULL
 )
```

Notice that i added the "IsCode" column - at the head of your question it existed, but in the create table didn't - so i assume is there.

The insert statements you do could be changed to this:

```
INSERT INTO @tableX([ID],[Code1],[Code2],[Sold],[Money1],[Money2],[IsCode])
SELECT
  pack1.ID,
  pack1.Code1,
  pack1.Code2,
  pack1.Sold,
  pack1.Money1,
  (CASE WHEN pack1.IsCode = 1 THEN pack1.Money1/pack1.Sold ELSE NULL END),
  pack1.IsCode
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS [ID],'GB' AS [Code1],'GB' AS [Code2],10 AS [Sold],100.000000 AS [Money1],1 AS [IsCode]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,'2GB','2GB',5,150.000000,1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,'AB',NULL,0,150.000000,0
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,'CB','BK',1,150.000000,0
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,NULL,'DE',NULL,150.000000,1) AS pack1

SELECT * FROM @tableX WHERE IsCode=1
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'total','total',SUM(Sold),SUM(Money1),(SUM(Money1)/SUM(Sold)),1 FROM @tableX WHERE IsCode=1
```

Alternativaly, you could place the inserts as you did, and after then run a `UPDATE` just on the Money2 column. Then proceed with the final select that calls all the data and a "total" line at the end.

Answer (score 1):

1- In order to fill the Money2 column with values:

```
update  #tableX set Money2 = 
case isnull(Sold,0) when 0 then Null else CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Money1/Sold) end where iscode = 1
```

Note that I have rounded the ratio Money1/Sold to the second decimal.

2- In order to insert the summary row in the table, there are many scenarios that I would take into consideration.

a- You want to compute a summary per ID (in your case on ID = 1 only exists, but in case you have many IDs)

```
insert into #tableX 
select ID , 'ttl','ttl',sum(Sold) Sold,Sum(isnull(Money1,0)) Money1 ,
case isnull(Sum(Sold),0) when 0 then Null else CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Sum(Money1)/Sum(Sold)) end  Money2,0 as iscode
from #tableX
where iscode = 1 and isnull(sold,0) <> 0
Group by ID
```

In this case, you will have multiple summary lines for each ID.

b- ID is irrelevant, you only want one line for the entire dataset

```
 insert into #tableX 
 select 99999999 , 'ttl','ttl',sum(Sold) Sold,Sum(isnull(Money1,0)) Money1 ,
 case isnull(Sum(Sold),0) when 0 then Null else CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Sum(Money1)/Sum(Sold)) end  Money2,0 as iscode
 from #tableX
 where iscode = 1 and isnull(sold,0) <> 0
```